# Keyboard-layout changes automatically (xfce)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, kile

Apparently I have many keyboard-layout processes running. I'm on XFCE and let run a startup-application by

```
 setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll en,fr,de,latam
```

Then it starts with `en`, but when I open `Kile` jumps to `fr`, which I don't wish. I have tried the GUI-settings "gobal, application, window" but no result. `kile` starts with `fr`. This is anoying because I compile and see the `pdf`, and if I switch windows, `evince` also automatically starts with `fr`. French was the first language I had there by default, i.e. that command was once

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll fr,en,de,latam
```

Worse yet, I opened a new user and when I start the keyboard manager, it has the same four languages without having ordered that. How can I erase absolutely all keyboard configurations by default? Or better, fix only this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To change the default user language, run **Language support** in **Settings** and drag your preferred installed language to the top of the list and hit **Apply**.  If you click **Apply for all users** it will make this language the default system language so that new users will automatically use the new language instead.

You can do the same for locales on the second tab and configure both the user and the default system locale there.

In order to stop the keyboard from changing layouts on a per application basis, add the **Keyboard Layouts** plugin on a panel, open its properties and change the last option to **Globally**.  That will keep the same keyboard layout no matter what you run.

Comment: Well, that I had done. I have a list of keyboard-managers and with no one but `iBus` I managed to fix it. Now, I am using Polish, but there are no special (non-roman) characters, is just plain English, unfortunately. Also, no short cut to change keyboard layout.